# Angular not loading from salesforce

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

Below error is throwing when I am trying to load angular app from an apex page. I am calling a function available in static resource from a VF page which loads the angular app.

It works on IE edge but fails on IE 11. I tried adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11,chrome=1" />` but with no luck.

Below is the error:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
   at Anonymous function (https://cpact--dev--c.cs6.visual.force.com/resource/1501785067000/bottlerFeedbackLibs/libs/js/angular.min.js:103:414)
   at n (https://cpact--dev--c.cs6.visual.force.com/resource/1501785067000/bottlerFeedbackLibs/libs/js/angular.min.js:100:147)
   at Anonymous function (https://cpact--dev--c.cs6.visual.force.com/resource/1501785067000/bottlerFeedbackLibs/libs/js/angular.min.js:97:357)
   at Anonymous function (https://cpact--dev--c.cs6.visual.force.com/resource/1501785067000/bottlerFeedbackLibs/libs/js/angular.min.js:132:10)
   at m.prototype.$eval (https://cpact--dev--c.cs6.visual.force.com/resource/1501785067000/bottlerFeedbackLibs/libs/js/angular.min.js:146:282)
   at m.prototype.$digest (https://cpact--dev--c.cs6.visual.force.com/resource/1501785067000/bottlerFeedbackLibs/libs/js/angular.min.js:143:412)
   at m.prototype.$apply (https://cpact--dev--c.cs6.visual.force.com/resource/1501785067000/bottlerFeedbackLibs/libs/js/a
```

Angular js version is `AngularJS v1.5.9`. I am stuck on it, if you guys have any idea kindly guide me at least steps which I can follow to debug this out to resolution.

Thanks.......

Comment: Please add code where you are initializing the Angular.. It works in all other browsers ? 
These two   links are helpful.. 
http://www.algoworks.com/blog/develop-salesforce-visualforce-apps-using-angularjs/ 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/07/building-single-page-app-angularjs-salesforce-rest-api.html

Comment: Add your Visualforce page to question